# XSL: Display value if not equal to -1.0000

Tags: xslt

I currently have a field in my xsl as follows:

```
<s:FineAmount>
<xsl:value-of select="FineAmount" />
</s:FineAmount>
```

The issue is the the value of the field can be '-1.0000'. I do not want to send the value if it is -1.0000. How can I filter it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<xsl:if>` - see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl%3aif). A good point to start learning XSLT is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp).

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: The way I want my optput to look like is, if 'FineAmount' =-1.000, then display empty node <FineAmount /> else display value <FineAmount>20</FineAmount>